# Decrease $x$ when $y$ increases

Tags: functions

I know this is probably really simple, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Basically, I need to figure out how to do the following.

> When $x = 0.75$, I want $y$ to equal $1.0$.
>
> When $x = 1.0$, I want $y$ to equal $0.65$.

I appreciate all the help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependance of $x$ and $y$ in your case is linear (i.e. $y = ax + b$ for some $a$ and $b$). Your conditions lead to the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
0.65 &= 1 \cdot a + b,\\
1 &= 0.75 \cdot a + b.
\end{cases}$$
You just need to find $a$ and $b$. Finally you obtain
$$
y = -\frac{7}{5} x + \frac{41}{20}.
$$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: You can find the equation $y-y_1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$ in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form